# Using health and Nike+ ipod app

Tags: ipod, health.app

1. If I want to use these 2 apps do I need any sensor to check about the health related data available in app
2. If no external device or sensor is required then how to use health and nike+ ipod app

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an iPod (e.g. nano as I do), then the trainings won't be synced to Health App. Otherwise using Nike+ Running App your runs will be automatically synced with Health App as far as you added Running App as a source in the Health App.
What I personally find disappointing, that Nike doesn't take a use of a step counter of an iPod and leave all the data on the iPod.

[image: Responce from Nike+ support]

Comment: Furthermore I provided my personal feedback that Nike should work on some solution for better iPod integration into the Health App of iOS. Let's hope that many of YOU do the same and they will really work out some solution. :)